# Can someone help me with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

Dropdown is not working can someone help me!!

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="btn-group" appDropdown>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage Recipe <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a>To Shopping List</a></li>
                <li><a (click)="onEditRecipe()"style="cursor: pointer;">Edit Recipe</a></li>
                <li><a style="cursor: pointer;">Delete Recipe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the console have any errors?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-toggle="dropdown"` to your button tag.

Comment: Yeah i have updated the code but its still not working

Comment: You may refer to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 0):

just use `data-toggle="dropdown"` and  `data-target="#navdrop"`